# iPhone In-Call Status Bar not resizing 'More' View

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When you toggle the In-Call Status Bar with the moreNavigationController displayed in a UITabBarController, the moreNavigationController does not resize like other views.

Is this something I can change in code or is it a bug in the SDK?

I'm using the iOS 4.2 SDK.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue, I think there's an issue in the UITabBarController, when toggling in-call , its view frame does not behave the same way as a standard UIViewController. Morever , the answer flagged as "answered" is not the right one I think, see my comment to this "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, the in-call status bar cannot simply appear while your app is running. The fact that you can do this in the Simulator is completely artificial.

Comment: So this will not happen in the app on a device?

Comment: When you answer a call, your application is suspended. The only time an in-call status bar can appear while an application is running is when it comes back forward from suspension. To test that, you can run your app, hit Home, toggle the in-call status bar, and then click on your app again in the simulator. This will bring it back forward. Naturally, if your app doesn't even support backgrounding, then this is a complete non-issue.

Comment: This isn't really true. Activating Personal Hotspot (and Internet Tethering before it) could be caused at any time without interacting with the iPhone, including in the middle of customizing a tab bar.

Comment: @Brian: That's interesting. I wrote that comment from the perspective of an AT&T customer, which meant that at the time of writing, there was no Personal Hotspot available for use. I was unaware that it had this behavior. Good to know.

Comment: @Kevin: I forgot that I'd installed the 4.3 beta a while back so I'd seen this behavior quite a while before everyone else  =)

Comment: No: this answer is simply not true : if you are in a call with someone, you can simply leave the native telephony app with the home button, browse all apps, start yours, and get your app with the in-call status bar appearing at the top of your app.

Comment: @yonel You seem to have completely mis-read this. Of course you can have your app running with the in-call status bar. Nobody's ever disputed that. The question is whether the in-call status bar can appear while your app is already running. Prior to Hotspot, this was impossible. According to @Brian, with Hotspot this can now happen.

Comment: @Kevin : oups sorry, yes the *while* is crucial here. Now I get what was meant here. thx :)